# Testing glassfish EJB with standard se application

Tags: java, glassfish-3, jndi, ejb-3.1

***Context #1 :***

A glassfish 3.1 server on my pc.

A simple ejb depoyed on the server.

In eclipse (same pc) :

```
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial","com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
    String jndiname = "java:global/simpleEjb";
    Context context = new InitialContext(p);
    System.out.println(daoService.sayHello());

}
```

}

In my pom.xml :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.appclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>gf-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:\Java\glassfish3\glassfish\lib\gf-client.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

and it's working.

***The real context :***

Glassfish is running on an ubuntu server on another machine.

So in my app :

```
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial","com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
    p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost","10.12.3.93");
    p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort","3700");
```

- If I leave my local server running : It's calling the ejb on my local server !!
- If I stop my local server : No exceptions but my app never ends (hanging on the lookup - even after waiting for more than 10 minutes).

I also tried modifying my pom.xml replacing the previous dependency with :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.appclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>gf-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
```

and adding :

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>EclipseLink</id>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

But same results ...

I'm going to become mad ... I don't understand what's happening.

If I try changing the host ip :

```
Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: 10.12.3.94; port: 3700
```

Comment: What happens when you set the system property: System.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost","10.12.3.93")? Or as a JVM option -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=10.12.3.93?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the solution :

There was a 'problem' in my /etc/hosts file.

There was :

myserver 127.0.0.1

and I replaced by

myserver 10.12.3.93