# JElastic deployment not working

Tags: connection, jndi, jelastic

I have developed a ejb application and deployed in glassfish then locally worked. But when I deployed to JElastic it is not working.

I have used glassfish 4.0 locally but 3.1.2.2 in jelastic.

It gives the following error

Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: (host)

My properties are ...

```
        Properties props = new Properties();


    props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",
            "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
            props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",
            "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
            props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state",
            "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");


            props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", Server);
            props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", Port);

            ContextObject = new InitialContext(props);
```

My lookup name is
InterfaceObject =ContextObject.lookup("java:global/ContextName/EJBJarname/BusinessClassName");

What is the solution to it...?

Advance thanks.
Mahavir .D

Answer (score 1):

Potentlially, problems related to /etc/hosts file could cause issue you experienced (specific record absence there). I would like to review [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706461/testing-glassfish-ejb-with-standard-se-application) where issue is already resolved additionally I would recommend contacting your Jelastic Support to review your hosts file in cooperaion.